# Why building of gradle can't be finished?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, gradle

I have everything updated to latest versions. I checked JDK - it works, I have installed these packages: lib32z1 lib32ncurses5-dev lib32stdc++6 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386. When I trying to run my app building of gradile never stops. 
Logs:

```
2:09:20 AM Gradle sync started
2:10:22 AM Gradle sync completed
2:10:27 AM Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]
```

Gradile console:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2320Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources
AAPT err(Facade for 1767133010): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1969709623): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1006614347): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1785369662): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1881902230): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 996071813): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 2137684494): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 202834109): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1759893362): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1712078357): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 13911109): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1936794562): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 273220858): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1981849064): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1056584022): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_2" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_5" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_3" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
AAPT err(Facade for 995994054): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 564585174): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 955623687): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 19057521): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
AAPT err(Facade for 1612347429): /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt: error while loading shared libraries: libz.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_6" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_8" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_9" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_7" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_10" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_11" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_12" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_14" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_13" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_15" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_17" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_16" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_20" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_19" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Exception in thread "png-cruncher_18" java.lang.RuntimeException: Timed out while waiting for slave aapt process, make sure the aapt execute at /home/user/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt can run successfully (some anti-virus may block it) or try setting environment variable SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT to a value bigger than 5 seconds
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess.waitForReady(AaptProcess.java:108)
    at com.android.builder.png.QueuedCruncher$1.creation(QueuedCruncher.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.tasks.WorkQueue.run(WorkQueue.java:203)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you doing the build from command line or within Android Studio IDE? What does the log says? Does all the maven repositories or repositories are available? Are you behind any firewall or proxy?

Comment: @Ashu I have added the logs.

Comment: Based on your logs 'SLAVE_AAPT_TIMEOUT' is happening...don't know much about your mobile app...**libz.so.1** couldn't load that shared object...

Comment: @Ashu it's just newly created app with one empty activity.

Answer (score 0):

just try to install `lib32z1` by doing:

```
apt-get install lib32z1
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Go to Settings -> "Build, Execution, Deployment" -> "Gradle".
- Under Project-level settings select "use default gradle wrapper".